# WiX Installer Fails To Launch - Error 0x80070005

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.10

I'm trying to install the 3.10.2 version of the Wix Toolset Installer but when I launch the installer nothing happens.  Pulling up the log file reveals the following errors:

```
[15A4:1580][2016-03-04T07:54:57]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to launch clean room process: C:\Users\MALLAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\{BA709DF5-6D54-418B-9760-DD363E3FE5DD}\.cr\wix310.exe
[15A4:1580][2016-03-04T07:54:57]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to run untrusted mode.
```

I am unable to find anything related to this error.

Comment: 3.10.2 introduced the clean room concept to mitigate dll hijacking attacks.  0x8007005 is access denied, but the path is your user's AppData folder so that shouldn't happen.  Do you have an antivirus that is blocking it?

Comment: I've tried disabling AV, but no luck.

Comment: Turns out Network Support pushed some group policy down that was interfering with the installation process.

Comment: Do you mind sharing which group policy they turned on?  I'm interested in the details of the interference, and other people will probably run into this.

Comment: I stand corrected, this was not a group policy problem.  This particular problem was caused by a local issue that I doubt anyone else would experience.  Our IT had made a modification to our AV profile that blocked any installer that decompressed to a temp directory unless it was executed from a well-defined location.  Once I launched the installer from the correct directory all was well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.10.2 introduced the clean room concept to mitigate dll hijacking attacks.  This involves copying itself to a clean folder in the user's temp directory and then doing most of the work from that new process.  Aggressive AV products might interfere with this.  For more information about clean room see http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/5184-burn-clean-room/ and https://www.firegiant.com/blog/2016/1/20/wix-v3.10.2-released/.